# To check if the app was opened from a widget in an Xcode plugin

Tags: ios, swift, typescript, xcode, plugins

I have an app that I wrote in ionic. I transferred this app to Xcode and added a widget as an additional feature. I created a swift file in Xcode to communicate with ionic. I can communicate, but I have a problem. I want to get whether the app was opened from a widget or from the normal icon in this swift file. How can I do it?

Plugin.swift:

```
import Foundation
import Capacitor

@objc(MyService)
public class MyService: CAPPlugin {

    @objc func routeProfile(_ call: CAPPluginCall) {
        print(bridge?.webView?.url)
        print("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb")
        print(bridge?.description)
        print("cccccccccccccccccccccccc")
        print(Bundle.main.bundlePath)
        print("dddddddddddddddddddddddd")
        print(Bundle.main.infoDictionary)
        print(Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleIdentifier"])
        print("cxvxvxcgsfgbdfdfgbdfb")
        print(externalURLScheme())
                                   //print(externalURLScheme)
        print(Bundle.main)
        if Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier == "com.xxx.yyy" {
                //UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(setting)
            print("here")
            } else {
                call.resolve(["a":"b"])
            }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

### `widgetURL` and `onOpenURL`

In your widget view, you can send an arbitrary URL to your app using [`widgetURL`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/View/widgetURL(_:)). In your app's outer view, you receive a URL in [`onOpenURL(perform:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onopenurl(perform:)/). If you do receive a URL, you can compare these  to determine if the widget has opened the app.

If you do not receive a URL (the `perform` action does not run), there are still other reasons why the app could have been started, like a notification. If you can exclude all other causes, your app has been started by tapping the app icon.